# the problems of let in for loop only executed once

Tags: javascript

The following code outer layer for loop is only executed once, wonderfully, why?

```js
let x = -5;
let y = -5;

for (; x < 5; ++x) {
  for (; y < 5; ++y) {
    console.log(x);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because once all inner iterations have finished on the first outer iteration, `y` is 5, so on the next outer iteration, the condition for the inner iteration (`y < 5`) is false - the inner loop body never runs again.

Comment: But will the initialization statement be written in (), the value of the inner loop will be updated?

Comment: If the variable is initialized in the `for` loop declaration, then every time that loop is initialized again, that variable will be initialized again. In contrast, right now, you just have two global variables that get incremented and stay there.

Comment: I got it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

No! Outer loop gets executed till x reaches 4 i.e. <5.
you are not resetting value of y before going to inner loop so condition of y is not satisfied and hence its not getting executed.

try putting console.log() before inner loop, then you will get idea of iterations happening.

Comment: I know that the outer loop will update the initialization parameter of the inner loop, but the parameter needs to be restricted to the outer loop. thank you very much